# Antd does not validate form fields

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to insert user data values ​​into the form, but they do not have a successful validation status

Added values ​​for fields to the form via useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth) {
   form.setFields(initialPersonalFields)
  }
}, [])
```

The value itself is displayed in the fields, but they do not receive the status of validated and are not styled accordingly, although the submission with the validation check processes correctly and sees them as validated and does not throw an error. If you start writing in these fields, they also begin to work correctly; when necessary, it gives an error; when I fill it in manually, it correctly sets the status to “success”

Comment: What's the version of antd?

Answer (score 0):

Antd form values are only auto validated on change and on submit events, when you fill form values it will not validate these values until one of these events happens or if you force validation with `form.validateFields()`, so your code should look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do nothing if auth is invalid
  if (!auth) return 

  form.setFields(initialPersonalFields)
  form.validateFields()
}, [])
```